# La parola "capo" può significare "angolo"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> C’erano sei ceri accesi ai quattro **capi** e a metà del letto. Tutta la stanza sapeva di cera consumata e di fiori.

La mia domanda è: i "quattro capi" di cui si parla qui sono i quattro angoli del letto? Ho cercato il vocabolo "capo" in alcuni dizionari, ma non sono riuscita a trovare questa accezione.

Comment: Effettivamente per capo del letto si intende la spalliera o testiera, dove si poggia la testa. Nel caso da te citato però per capo mi sembra si intendano i quattro angoli, anche perchè viene specificato che i restanti due ceri fossero posizionati a metà del letto.

Comment: Concordo. In questo caso capo = estremità = angolo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effettivamente per capo del letto si intende la spalliera o testiera, dove si poggia la testa. Nel caso da te citato però per capo mi sembra si intendano i quattro angoli, anche perché viene specificato che i restanti due ceri fossero posizionati a metà del letto.

Da Treccani per [capo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/capo_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/):

> 3. (fig.) [parte più alta, parte terminale o principio di qualcosa: in c. alla scala] ≈ cima, estremità, inizio, sommità.

Seguendo il senso di questa accezione, come già sottolineato da @RiccardoDeContardi, capo essendo sinonimo di estremità in questo caso si riferisce all'angolo, anche perché i quattro angoli delimitano il letto.